# Laravel relationships avoid query where foreign key is null

Tags: laravel, orm, laravel-5, eloquent

When eager loading, is it possible to avoid doing an extra query when the foreign key in a relationship is null and therefore does not match any related record? In my example I have a `Product` and `User`.

A `Product` is owned by a `User` but can also be optionally edited by a `User`. So my model looks like this:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function editor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'editor_id');
    }
}
```

When a product has not been edited, it's `editor_id` attribute is `NULL`.

If I hadn't been eager loading I know I could do something like the following:

```
$product = Product::find(1);
if (!is_null($product->editor_id)) {
    // Load the relation
}
```

However, this isn't an option for me and I would ideally like to avoid an extra, unnecessary query being run when eager loading:

```
Query: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` in (?)
Bindings: [0]
```

I was wondering if something similar to the following would be possible?

```
public function editor()
{
    if (!is_null($this->editor_id)) {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'editor_id');
    }
}
```

When doing the above I get this error:

```
Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on a non-object
```

I'm guessing that this is because it's not guaranteed that this method returns a `Relation` object.

Thanks

Comment: Is it just a typo in your post or you actually run this code? Because `USer::class` should be `User::class`.

Comment: Ok so you can't do it like that, your relationship have to return something otherwise, Laravel tries to call a method on null

Comment: use whereHas condition,maybe it will help you.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your responses. @PeterPan666 - Yeah I know it needs to return something and that's why I got the error. @Imtiaz Pabel - How would I use `whereHas` in this scenario? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating a new `Relation` subclass that implements the required methods but simply returns null when actually obtaining results:

```
namespace My\App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

class NullRelation extends Relation {

    public function __construct() {}

    public function addConstraints() {}

    public function addEagerConstraints(array $models) {}

    public function initRelation(array $models, $relation) {}

    public function match(array $models, Collection $results, $relation) {
        return [];
    }

    public function getResults() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Then inside your relation method(s) you can check for null and return an instance of `NullRelation` instead:

```
public function editor() {
    if ($this->editor_id === null) {
        return new NullRelation();
    } else {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'editor_id');
    }
}
```

It's a bit ugly and you'd be repeating youself a lot, so if I were using this in more than one place I'd probably create a subclass of the `Model`, then create versions of the `belongsTo`, `hasOne` methods and perform the check there:

```
public function belongsToIfNotNull($related, $foreignKey = null, $otherKey = null, $relation = null) {
    if ($this->$foreignKey === null) {
        return new NullRelation();
    } else {
        return parent::belongsTo($related, $foreignKey, $otherKey, $relation);
    }
}
```

Finally in your modal that inherits the new subclass, your relation method simply becomes

```
public function editor() {
    return $this->belongsToIfNotNull(User::class, 'editor_id');
}
```

Comment: +1 I really like your approach. I would even consider going as far as simply overriding the default relation methods on the model class to do this as I find the extra query totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Docs

**Querying Relations When Selecting**

When accessing the records for a model, you may wish to limit your results based on the existence of a relationship.

```
 $posts= Post::has('editor')->get();
```

You may also specify an operator and a count:

```
  $posts = Post::has('editor', '>=', 3)->get();
```