# Laravel 7 - Prevent eloquent relation from query DB if null

Tags: php, laravel

I have read similiar topics such as:

- [Laravel Eloquent - Do not run relationship query if column value is NULL or 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699673/laravel-eloquent-do-not-run-relationship-query-if-column-value-is-null-or-0) and
- [Laravel relationships avoid query where foreign key is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773634/laravel-relationships-avoid-query-where-foreign-key-is-null)
- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/29622

But I'm unable to find a solution to my problem. Thanks to **Laravel DebugBar**, I found out that I have multiple queries hitting DB without the need to.

[image]

This three relations all belong to a model called Invoices.

```
<?php    

class Invoices extends Model
{
    public function location()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\Models\Locations', 'id', 'location_id');
    }
    
    public function vehicle()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\Models\Vehicles', 'id', 'vehicle_id');
    }

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\Models\Employees', 'id', 'employee_id');
    }
}
```

And all I do is call the relations as follows:

```
$invoice = \App\Models\Invoices::with('vehicle')
    ->with('employee')
    ->with('location')
    ->first();
```

It doesn't matter if I use `belongsTo` or `hasOne`, the query is always performed with `NULL` values.

How can I prevent the query from being executed with `NULL` values **yet** maintaning the relationship? I'd like the output of `$invoice` to be:

```
"invoices": 
{
    "other_relationship": {...},
    "other_relationship": {...},
    "vehicle": null,
    "employee": null,
    "location": null,
}
```

Besides the quoted links, I also tried this approach https://github.com/mendicm/framework/commit/26214b2c46b580a799f2748dc28698e958d3e995 without success, probably because of the version incompatibility.

**Edit 1**: Another way to illustrate the problem

[image]

Comment: I don't think your problem lies in this code. Can you show us how you're outputting the JSON for `$invoice` you have at the end of your question? Is this via an API resource or something? IIRC, the DebugBar will tell you what line of application code generated the query.

Comment: @ceejayoz doesn't even matter the output, because I'm looking at the Laravel DebugBar and I see the queries being performed without the need to. If I'm able to avoid this, the data of `$invoice` will be rectified. It's not a JSON, I just wrote that as an example.

Comment: I get that the queries are being performed. I don't think they're being performed by *this code*. If you `return` right after the query, do you still see all three spurious queries?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes. I just wrote something even simpler: `$invoice = \App\Models\Invoices::with('employee')->first(); return true;` and the DebugBar shows the same behavior (but now only with `employee`, obviously)

Comment: I've just tested locally and cannot reproduce this. If my query returns no results, the relationship queries do not run. (In my case, `\App\Models\User::whereEmail('doesntexist@gmail.com')->with('posts')->first()`; there's no resulting posts query.)

Comment: Wait, my code returns values !! all I want is the relations to not be performed if they are null !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Solved**.

After some hard digging, many hours with break-points, and actually saving every `SELECT` statement in DB to know exactly when is the query being executed, I found where does Laravel Framework performs a DB query and, specially, where I could implement a condition to avoid the **UNNEEDED** database query.

I initially thought that I would have to mess with `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne.php` class, since I'm using a `HasOne` relationship, but I couldn't be more wrong.

**Step 1)**

Open the file `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php`

**Step 2)**

Find the function `get`:

```
/**
 * Execute the query as a "select" statement.
 *
 * @param  array|string  $columns
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
 */
public function get($columns = ['*'])
{
    $builder = $this->applyScopes();

    // If we actually found models we will also eager load any relationships that
    // have been specified as needing to be eager loaded, which will solve the
    // n+1 query issue for the developers to avoid running a lot of queries.
    if (count($models = $builder->getModels($columns)) > 0) {
        $models = $builder->eagerLoadRelations($models);
    }

    return $builder->getModel()->newCollection($models);
}
```

**Step 3)**

Change it as follows:

```
/**
 * Execute the query as a "select" statement.
 *
 * @param  array|string  $columns
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
 */
public function get($columns = ['*'])
{
    $builder = $this->applyScopes();

    $ignoreQuery = 
        isset($this->query->wheres) &&             
        isset($this->query->wheres[0]['type']) &&
        isset($this->query->wheres[0]['values']) &&
        count($this->query->wheres) == 1 &&
        count($this->query->wheres[0]['values']) == 1 &&
        $this->query->wheres[0]['type'] == 'In' &&
        is_null($this->query->wheres[0]['values'][0]);

    // Returns an empty collection KEEPING, however, the relationship !
    if ($ignoreQuery)
        return $builder->getModel()->newCollection([]);

    // If we actually found models we will also eager load any relationships that
    // have been specified as needing to be eager loaded, which will solve the
    // n+1 query issue for the developers to avoid running a lot of queries.
    if (count($models = $builder->getModels($columns)) > 0) {
        $models = $builder->eagerLoadRelations($models);
    }

    return $builder->getModel()->newCollection($models);
}
```

The variable `$this->query` holds the following data for each relationship:

```
{
  "connection": {},
  "grammar": {},
  "processor": {},
  "bindings": {
    "select": [],
    "from": [],
    "join": [],
    "where": [
      null
    ],
    "groupBy": [],
    "having": [],
    "order": [],
    "union": [],
    "unionOrder": []
  },
  "aggregate": null,
  "columns": null,
  "distinct": false,
  "from": "employees",
  "joins": null,
  "wheres": [
    {
      "type": "In",
      "column": "employees.id",
      "values": [
        null
      ],
      "boolean": "and"
    }
  ],
  "groups": null,
  "havings": null,
  "orders": null,
  "limit": null,
  "offset": null,
  "unions": null,
  "unionLimit": null,
  "unionOffset": null,
  "unionOrders": null,
  "lock": null,
  "operators": [
    "=",
    "<",
    ">",
    "<=",
    ">=",
    "<>",
    "!=",
    "<=>",
    "like",
    "like binary",
    "not like",
    "ilike",
    "&",
    "|",
    "^",
    "<<",
    ">>",
    "rlike",
    "not rlike",
    "regexp",
    "not regexp",
    "~",
    "~*",
    "!~",
    "!~*",
    "similar to",
    "not similar to",
    "not ilike",
    "~~*",
    "!~~*"
  ],
  "useWritePdo": false
}
```

So as you can see by comparing my `if statement` I check & double-check several things to make sure I avoid the **UNNEEDED** following query statements:

```
select * from `vehicles` where `vehicles`.`id` in ('')
select * from `employees` where `employees`.`id` in ('')
select * from `locations` where `locations`.`id` in ('')
```

Through all my software I have many relationships who happen to have no value sometimes and so I've manage to drastically reduce the amount of queries.

**Important & Keep in mind that**, such query:

```
$invoices = \App\Models\Invoices::with('vehicle')->with('employee')->with('location')->first();
```

**Will still return the relationship** AS `NULL`, but without having performed the DB query, which is what I was aiming for !

Comment: This will be overwritten the next time the library updates.  It's be better to extend the base class and then substitute it in laravel's calls.  I don't know the exact procedure to do that since I haven't had to do it myself, but roughly speaking you'd need to find the service provider that creates an instance of the class, and replace it with your own service provider that provides an instance of your class, and then add it in the appropriate configuration/registration location(never directly edit the vendor folder).

Comment: @Daedalus it's a good suggestion however, it's 2023, Laravel current version is 10 and I'm using version 7 on this project, which means...I don't intend to update the libraries / framework, so there's nothing to worry about.